# Why can't I set the Opacity in this situation?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, tabcontrol, opacity

Here's the situation... at the top level, I have a TabControl.  Each page in the TabControl consists of a ListBox:

```xml
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="item 1">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>sub item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>sub item 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>sub item 3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="item 2">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>sub item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>sub item 2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The ListBoxes have a horizontally-oriented StackPanel as their ListTemplate:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                      VisibleChanged="onStackPanelVisibilityChange"
                      Loaded="onStackPanelLoaded"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You'll notice I have some event handlers on that stack panel.  Those are to animate the items within the stack panel, so they fade into view sequentially.  The event handlers are implemented as:

```cs
void onStackPanelLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel panel = sender as StackPanel;

    applySubItemAnimations(panel);
}

void onStackPanelVisibilityChange(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel panel = sender as StackPanel;

    if (panel.IsVisible)
    {
        applySubItemAnimations(panel);
    }
}

private void applySubItemAnimations(StackPanel panel)
{
    DoubleAnimation fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation();
    fadeIn.DecelerationRatio = 0.1;
    fadeIn.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500));
    fadeIn.From = 0.0;
    fadeIn.To = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < panel.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        panel.Children[i].Opacity = 0.0;
        fadeIn.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200 * i + 50);
        panel.Children[i].BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeIn);
    }
}
```

For the most part, this works great.  When you first click on (or load) a tab, the sub-items in the stack panel fade into view one-after-the-other.  The problem is when you click back to a tab that's already been shown once before (ie, you're in the "VisibleChanged" event handler rather than the "Loaded" handler), all the items are already shown and they *blink* in order, rather than starting as hidden and being *shown* in order.

Here's where it gets ugly.  This line:

```cs
panel.Children[i].Opacity = 0.0;
```

... does nothing.  If I step through the code in the debugger and put a watch on "panel.Children[i].Opacity", it stays right at 1.0.  No exception or anything.  It just... doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the output window, wpf does not throw exceptions in many cases but writes to output window.

Comment: Nothing popped up there, but a good tip (especially for a WPF n00b like myself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a guess on what might be happening:
WPF does not remove animations once they are completed, so when your code runs through the `applySubItemsAnimations` method for the second time, the previous animations are still there. Therefore you could try to remove these animations by passing **null** as second parameter to

```
panel.Children[i].BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null);
```

Afterwards, you can apply the new animation, so the whole `for`-loop would look like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < panel.Children.Count; i++)
{            
    panel.Children[i].Opacity = 0.0;            
    fadeIn.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200 * i + 50);            
    panel.Children[i].BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null);        
    panel.Children[i].BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeIn);        
}
```

Comment: Had exactly the same issue as this and funnily enough, it sounds like dkeen is writing almost exactly the same type of control as I am! Thanks.